# String concat leads to strange string to double conversion

Tags: asp.net, string, vb.net, parsing, double

I have no clue what is going on with this code.  I have looked at it from a bunch of different perspectives of what could be causing this issue and everything has come up nil.

So, the issue is that after a certain number of characters, my code is trying to execute a string to double conversion on its own during a string contcat.  I have looked for any input that I was not converting to a string, checked for missing " or + operands, I have even tried moving sections of the code around to see if it was a specific page control value causing the issue.

Nothing has worked, no matter what fields I put into the concatenation it tries to convert the string to a double after around 16 to 20 characters.

Here is the concat that is causing the problems:

```
thCValLst = "AhcccsGroup = " + If(ThCredAhcsGrpCBox.Checked, "1", "0") + ", NPI = '" + ThCredNPITBox.Text + "', AhcccsActive = " + If(ThCredAhcsActCBox.Checked, "1", "0") + "', DriversLicense = '"
                thCValLst += ThCredDrvLicTBox.Text + "', EINNumber = '" + ThCredEINTBox.Text + "', Credentials = '" + ThCredCredTBox.Text + "', Contracted = '" + ThCredConTBox.Text + "', Notes = '" + ThCredNotesTBox.Text + "', CPRExpDate = '"
                thCValLst += CType(ThCredCPREDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', LCRExpDate = '" + CType(ThCredLCREDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', FingerPrintTakenDate = '"
                thCValLst += CType(ThCredFPTDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', FingerPrintExpDate = '" + CType(ThCredFPEDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', LicenseNumber = '" + ThCredLicNumTBox.Text
                thCValLst += "', LicenseExpDate = '" + CType(ThCredLEDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', InsuranceExpDate = '" + CType(ThCredIEDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', Article9ExpDate = '"
                thCValLst += CType(ThCredA9DDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "', MalpracticeDate = " + If(ThCredMPDDTP.SelectedDate Is Nothing, "NULL", "'" + CType(ThCredMPDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'")
                thCValLst += ", PreSuppExpiration = " + If(ThCredPSEDDTP.SelectedDate Is Nothing, "NULL", "'" + CType(ThCredPSEDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "'") + ", TermDate = '" + CType(ThCredTDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                thCValLst += "', BillingAuthSheet = " + If(ThCredABSCBox.Checked, "1", "0") + ", SignedContract = " + If(ThCredSCCBox.Checked, "1", "0") + ", PayrollInfo = " + If(ThCredPRICBox.Checked, "1", "0") + ", W9 = " + If(ThCredW9CBox.Checked, "1", "0")
                thCValLst += ", Resume = " + If(ThCredResCBox.Checked, "1", "0") + ", Referenece = " + If(ThCredRefCBox.Checked, "1", "0") + ", Orientation = " + If(ThCredOrtCBox.Checked, "1", "0") + ", InsCode1 = '" + ThCredInsCd1TBox.Text + "', InsCode2 = '"
                thCValLst += ThCredInsCd2TBox.Text + "', Facility = '" + ThCredFacTBox.Text = "', ModifiedOn = GetDate(), ModifiedBy = '" + curUsr.GetUsrName() + "'"
```

In the above code, the execution gets to the eighth character of the NPI value before it throws the double conversion error which I will add in its entirety below.

thCValLst is defined : Dim thCValLst As String = "" and is never used until this point in my code.  I have other concats like this just above it in the code and those are fine.  I feel like I have missed something but I can't figure out what.  Everything looks like it should be correct.

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Conversion from string "AhcccsGroup = 1, NPI = '12345678" to type 'Double' is not valid.
>       at Function.Error.create (https://clinic.h2tportal.com/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ac9c7ac0d-8fa4-44a7-8b1a-8b20d0589515%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a48e0f2bb-99f7-43cd-9b8e-5b9bce752872%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a16d8629e%3aed16cbdc%3a962f9868%3a73973f5b%3a578015a3%3af46195d3%3a58366029%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae4f8f289%3a333f8d94%3a4cd1fec6%3a77613e24%3af0c58c30%3a9b7cc2d2%3a69667591%3aec7335e%3ad944e0f6%3ac442ac3f%3a8d1fecce%3a6b6b9ee5%3a595e7652%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a4877f69a%3a874f8ea2%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303%3ab7778d6c%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a82923ac3%3a6d43f6d9%3ac172ae1e%3a9cdfc6e7:6:2736)
>       at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._createPageRequestManagerServerError (https://clinic.h2tportal.com/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ac9c7ac0d-8fa4-44a7-8b1a-8b20d0589515%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a48e0f2bb-99f7-43cd-9b8e-5b9bce752872%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a16d8629e%3aed16cbdc%3a962f9868%3a73973f5b%3a578015a3%3af46195d3%3a58366029%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae4f8f289%3a333f8d94%3a4cd1fec6%3a77613e24%3af0c58c30%3a9b7cc2d2%3a69667591%3aec7335e%3ad944e0f6%3ac442ac3f%3a8d1fecce%3a6b6b9ee5%3a595e7652%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a4877f69a%3a874f8ea2%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303%3ab7778d6c%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a82923ac3%3a6d43f6d9%3ac172ae1e%3a9cdfc6e7:15:11490)
>       at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._parseDelta (https://clinic.h2tportal.com/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ac9c7ac0d-8fa4-44a7-8b1a-8b20d0589515%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a48e0f2bb-99f7-43cd-9b8e-5b9bce752872%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a16d8629e%3aed16cbdc%3a962f9868%3a73973f5b%3a578015a3%3af46195d3%3a58366029%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae4f8f289%3a333f8d94%3a4cd1fec6%3a77613e24%3af0c58c30%3a9b7cc2d2%3a69667591%3aec7335e%3ad944e0f6%3ac442ac3f%3a8d1fecce%3a6b6b9ee5%3a595e7652%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a4877f69a%3a874f8ea2%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303%3ab7778d6c%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a82923ac3%3a6d43f6d9%3ac172ae1e%3a9cdfc6e7:15:29608)
>       at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmitCompleted (https://clinic.h2tportal.com/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ac9c7ac0d-8fa4-44a7-8b1a-8b20d0589515%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a48e0f2bb-99f7-43cd-9b8e-5b9bce752872%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a16d8629e%3aed16cbdc%3a962f9868%3a73973f5b%3a578015a3%3af46195d3%3a58366029%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae4f8f289%3a333f8d94%3a4cd1fec6%3a77613e24%3af0c58c30%3a9b7cc2d2%3a69667591%3aec7335e%3ad944e0f6%3ac442ac3f%3a8d1fecce%3a6b6b9ee5%3a595e7652%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a4877f69a%3a874f8ea2%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303%3ab7778d6c%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a82923ac3%3a6d43f6d9%3ac172ae1e%3a9cdfc6e7:15:25637)
>       at Array. (https://clinic.h2tportal.com/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ac9c7ac0d-8fa4-44a7-8b1a-8b20d0589515%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a48e0f2bb-99f7-43cd-9b8e-5b9bce752872%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a16d8629e%3aed16cbdc%3a962f9868%3a73973f5b%3a578015a3%3af46195d3%3a58366029%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae4f8f289%3a333f8d94%3a4cd1fec6%3a77613e24%3af0c58c30%3a9b7cc2d2%3a69667591%3aec7335e%3ad944e0f6%3ac442ac3f%3a8d1fecce%3a6b6b9ee5%3a595e7652%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a4877f69a%3a874f8ea2%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303%3ab7778d6c%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a82923ac3%3a6d43f6d9%3ac172ae1e%3a9cdfc6e7:6:307)
>       at https://clinic.h2tportal.com/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ac9c7ac0d-8fa4-44a7-8b1a-8b20d0589515%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a48e0f2bb-99f7-43cd-9b8e-5b9bce752872%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a16d8629e%3aed16cbdc%3a962f9868%3a73973f5b%3a578015a3%3af46195d3%3a58366029%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae4f8f289%3a333f8d94%3a4cd1fec6%3a77613e24%3af0c58c30%3a9b7cc2d2%3a69667591%3aec7335e%3ad944e0f6%3ac442ac3f%3a8d1fecce%3a6b6b9ee5%3a595e7652%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a4877f69a%3a874f8ea2%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303%3ab7778d6c%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a82923ac3%3a6d43f6d9%3ac172ae1e%3a9cdfc6e7:6:51370
>       at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (https://clinic.h2tportal.com/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ac9c7ac0d-8fa4-44a7-8b1a-8b20d0589515%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a48e0f2bb-99f7-43cd-9b8e-5b9bce752872%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a16d8629e%3aed16cbdc%3a962f9868%3a73973f5b%3a578015a3%3af46195d3%3a58366029%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae4f8f289%3a333f8d94%3a4cd1fec6%3a77613e24%3af0c58c30%3a9b7cc2d2%3a69667591%3aec7335e%3ad944e0f6%3ac442ac3f%3a8d1fecce%3a6b6b9ee5%3a595e7652%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a4877f69a%3a874f8ea2%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303%3ab7778d6c%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a82923ac3%3a6d43f6d9%3ac172ae1e%3a9cdfc6e7:6:89728)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange (https://clinic.h2tportal.com/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_MainContent_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3ac9c7ac0d-8fa4-44a7-8b1a-8b20d0589515%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen-US%3a48e0f2bb-99f7-43cd-9b8e-5b9bce752872%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3a22a6274a%3a24ee1bba%3ae330518b%3a2003d0b8%3ac128760b%3a88144a7a%3a1e771326%3ac8618e41%3a1a73651d%3a16d8629e%3aed16cbdc%3a962f9868%3a73973f5b%3a578015a3%3af46195d3%3a58366029%3aaa288e2d%3a258f1c72%3ae4f8f289%3a333f8d94%3a4cd1fec6%3a77613e24%3af0c58c30%3a9b7cc2d2%3a69667591%3aec7335e%3ad944e0f6%3ac442ac3f%3a8d1fecce%3a6b6b9ee5%3a595e7652%3a92fe8ea0%3afa31b949%3a4877f69a%3a874f8ea2%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3a7c926187%3a8674cba1%3a2e42e72a%3aef347303%3ab7778d6c%3ac08e9f8a%3aa51ee93e%3a59462f1%3a82923ac3%3a6d43f6d9%3ac172ae1e%3a9cdfc6e7:6:84327)

Comment: If you are concat string, use the `&` operator, not the `+` consider using a StringBuilder for readability. Your problem is likely due to an attempted math operation within your madness.

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi Tried that and now the string's value is returned with the value of False making my update string "Update Table Set False Where ID = 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, I'm surprised that your code even compiles because there is no String concatenation symbol at the end of each line.

Something to consider is that while it is valid to use the `+` operator to concatenate Strings in Visual Basic, it is prefer to use the `&` operator. This will avoid any ambiguity between String concatenation and the mathematical operator for addition.

Something else to consider is that, depending on the version of Visual Studios that you're using, you should consider using String interpolation or String.Format to format your String.

**String Interpolation**
Introduced in Visual Basic 14 it allows you interpolate your Strings. The two lines in the following code return the same String (assuming variable names):

```
Dim foo As String = $"{variable1}: {variable2} - {variable3}"
Dim bar As String = variable1 & ": " & variable2 & " - " & variable2
```

In this case, the values represented in variable1, variable2, and variable3 will be included in the String, but notice how much easier it is to read the String literal. What's more is that the Visual Studio IDE colors the interpolated variables differently.

**String.Format** Is sort of a precursor to String interpolation. The two lines in the following code do the same thing as above:

```
Dim foo As String = String.Format("{0}: {1} - {2}", variable1, variable2, variable3)
Dim bar As String = variable1 & ": " & variable2 & " - " & variable2
```

I would suggest that you use one of the two methods outlined and see if that helps.

P.S. - I noticed that you're doing some type conversions such as `CType(ThCredFPTDDTP.SelectedDate, DateTime)`. There's really no reason for this since you're converting it from a Date to a Date to a String. If you want to convert a DateTime variable to a String call the ToString method while optionally passing the desired format: `ThCredFPTDDTP.SelectedDate.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy")`

*This suggestion was invalid because the controls are custom 3rd party controls*

P.S.S. - After our conversation it was determined that the person you inherited the code from was attempting to build a SQL query String by passing the values in the query String, i.e. using a parameterless query. I would suggest that you convert the code to utilize parameters for obvious SQL benefits, but also to improve readability.

Comment: The date conversions are neccessary.  Those controls are Telerik RadDateTime pickers which use a custom nullable date field.  This type is incompatible with the SQL Date/DateTime classes without casting to a normal Date/DateTime.

As for the first comment in your answer, each line is using the += operator on the string variable.  I am also using Visual Studio 2010 Shell, it does not compile the site as there is no solution.  We have set up asp/iis to compile the site during run time if there are changes.

Comment: @Geowil - Ah ok, that would make sense. Still, the other information should be useful. Also, just to confirm, you're not using a parameterless query are you?

Comment: In this instance we are, I have been working to move the queries toward that direction though.  For this specific page, almost all of the fields are pre-filled or date fields.  The ones that aren't I am scrubbing during an earlier function to prevent injections.  The original it admin that created the site left a hell of a mess.  It might be easier in this instance just to cut my losses and convert it now though.

Comment: @Geowil I can certainly sympathize with that statement. I would suggest converting the query to use parameters immediately. This will not only improve readability but it also sets a standard going forward that is easy to implement.

Comment: I attempting using & instead of + for the concanteation operator but it just treated it like an if statement and spat out a false instead of the set list.  I recoded it to use a parameterized update query and it works just fine now.  Might have been missing a ) some where for an if statement.  If you could, edit your answer with the parameterization suggestion and I will accept it.  Thanks.